# QGIS: Use 'replace' expression for 2 characters in one field calculation

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression

I have a field of currency values in an attribute table. As an example, I'm attempting to replace £10,000.00 to 10000.00 so QGIS can run graduated styles on the new field. The following replaces the £ sign with a blank character.

```
replace(  "field_name", '£', '')
```

I'm struggling to get rid of the comma in the same expression. I have tried:

```
replace(  "field_name", '£', '') || replace(  "field_name", ',', '')
```

but this returns 10,000.00£10000.00

The 'replace' expression doesn't seem to cater for more than one character to target as a replacement. Do I need to do this over 2 expressions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a nested replace() function such as

```
replace(replace('£10,000.00','£',''),',','')
```

You can nest as many replace() as you want.

Answer (score 9):

You can do both replacements using a single function call:

1) using `regex_replace`, where you would look for the two characters of interest (inside square brackets):

```
regexp_replace("field_name",'[£,]','')
```

or 2) the `map` variant of `replace`, where the map is a series of key-value, the key being the string being searched for and the value being the replacement string

```
replace("field_name",map('£','',',',''))
```